# ¿Como implementa el API de geolocalizacion de HTML 5 en movil?

Tags: javascript, html5

tengo una inquietud.

Estoy realizando una pagina que me solicite la localización y para esto uso el API de geolocalizacion que ofrece la W3C: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp"

Tengo mi modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Geolocacliacion</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="find()">Mostrar</button>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

    function find() {
      var salida = document.getElementById('map');
      if(navigator.geolocation) {
        salida.innerHTML = "<p>Si hay</p>";
      } else {
        salida.innerHTML = "<p>No hay</p>";
      }

      function localizacion(posicion) {
        var latitud = posicion.coords.latitude;
        var longitud = posicion.coords.longitude;
        var img = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitud + "," + longitud + "&size=600x300&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C" + latitud + ","+longitud+"&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C" + latitud + "," + longitud + "&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C"+latitud+","+longitud+"&key=KEY";


          salida.innerHTML = "<img src='"+img+"'>";
      }

      function error() {
        salida.innerHTML = "<p>No hay</p>";
      }

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(localizacion, error);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EL problema, y a lo que viene esta consulta, es como puedo implementar esto para acceder a la ubicación desde mi movil.

Lo ejecuta y funciona como esta en pc, pero no me aparece la ubicación y tampoco me envía la solicitud de acceso al GPS en el móvil(android).

Comment: te sugiero revisar el tutorial completo: https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-a-guide-geolocation-api

Comment: Gracias, lo revise pero cuando ejecuto la pagina en mi móvil no me aparece nada, ni me solicita el acceso a la localización; desde el equipo PC todo funciona normal.